# iOS - App is using a lot of CPU while seemingly not doing anything

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-management

When I run my app in Xcode, xcode tells me it is constantly 35% of the CPU, even though it appears that nothing is happening. Nothing is suppose to be happening, so I am surprised by the CPU usage. There is obviously a loop in the code, but I need to figure out how to locate it.

I'm trying to figure out how to locate the loop, perhaps using instruments, but I don't really know where to begin.

Does anyone have any advice on how to attack this problem? I have hit the "pause" button in Xcode, but it of course pauses on the compiled stack (or whatever that screen with a bunch of Hex values is called).

Thanks!

Comment: Try profiling your app. When used correctly, it very easily shows you where your "power" is going. Here's a tut to get you started :) http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-time-profiling-with-instruments/

Comment: You can locate loops in your code by searching for 'for' and 'while' keywords. Really.